# How to order 120 combinations for equitable distribution of judges

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

so I have a question regarding combinatorics. I have 10 judges for a scholarship, and I want 3 judges to read each essay entry. I know that I have 120 combinations of A-B-C, A-B-D... and I figure I'll randomize the essayIDs and then assign each submission a particular judge combination (and will restart for #121). That way each judge will be assigned to exactly 36 essays per 120 submissions.

But here's the catch -- I very much doubt that I'm going to receive exactly a multiple of 120 submissions. So if I receive 80 submissions, then I don't want judge A to grade 36 essays while judge J only grades 18. Obviously there are some submission counts where it won't be divisible by 10 and is literally impossible to be perfectly equal, but I want to keep deviation of the workload around 1-2 essays amongst all judges at any given point. So with that in mind... how can I best ORDER my 120 combinations to get equitable-ish appearances for each of my 10 elements at every point in the ordering?

Comment: Its 2024.  You can do it randomly with computer assistance and it should be close enough to what you want to avoid issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I had that idea already, but when I've done it randomly, all 3 times I randomized them, there was one judge that would be under-utilized until the last 30ish of the 120 combinations. And 2 of the 3 times there were at least 2 judges that would get ~5 more essays than the rest if we received 140-150 submissions.

And I suppose I was hoping there might be a more elegant mathematical solution, since depending on how many submissions we receive, we may scale the # of judges accordingly